# Why am I getting an index out of range in one place but not the other?

Tags: python, string, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

```
def extendedString(string1, string2):
    newString = ""
    if len(string1) == len(string2):
        for i in range(0, len(string1)):
            newString = newString + string1[i] + string2[i]
        return newString
    else:
        if len(string1) < len(string2):
            for i in range(0, len(string2)):
                string1 = string1 + string1[i - 1]
            for i in range(0, len(string1)):
                newString = newString + string1[i] + string2[i]
            return newString
        else:
            for i in range(0, len(string1)):
                string2 = string2 + string2[i - 1]
            for i in range(0, len(string2)):
                newString = newString + string1[i] + string2[i]
            return newString
```

Within the first if statement I use the code:

```
            newString = newString + string1[i] + string2[i]
```

And get no index out of bounds error but then in the else statement I use the exact same line of code on the 12th line and get an index out of range error, why is this?

Comment: Because `string1`, `string2` and `i` have different values?

Comment: I suggest you shoul print the values of those variables before the exception. Then you will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because in your if statement above, the two strings, "string1" and "string2" have the same length and hence can reference to equal amount of elements, i.

But in your error area, your if statement states that len(string1) < len(string2) and hence, can not have the same size i in the end.

They don't have the same i in string1[i] and string2[i] if one is larger.

In line 9,
Instead of:

```
for i in range(0, len(string2)):
```

Use:

```
for i in range(0, len(string1)):
```